# SAS Macro GLOBAL scope

Tags: global, sas, sas-macro

is there a short way to make ALL macro variables created inside a macro global in scope?

ie:

```
%macro x;  
 %global _all_;  * ??? ;  
 %let x=1;  
 %let y=1;  
 %let z=1;  
%mend;
```

Comment: Do you really want to do this? You can clobber already existing global macro variables with your local ones. And you are asking for a way to do this implicitly! It is a recommended practice to declare %LOCAL (never %GLOBAL) all the variables you use in a macro.

Comment: I absolutely agree with Chang Chung.  You can easily cause problems for yourself or others if you make this a standard practice.  If you absolutely have to do it, then try to ensure they are named using a prefix so that they won't be overwritten by accident.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I can think of to do this without having to declare each macro as global ahead of time and then do a %let statement is to use a macro ***in place of*** the %let statement.

In the code below, I create a macro called **%mylet** which has as its sole purpose the task of creating a global variable with the name and value I pass as arguments.  I then use this macro in place of %let everywhere I want global variables defined.

eg.

```
%global myvar;
%let myvar=2;
```

would become...

> `%mylet(myvar,2);`

```
/* Define a macro to declare variables as global */
%macro mylet(var,value);
  %global &var;
  %let &var.= &value ;
%mend;

/* Test macro */
%macro test;
 %mylet(myvar,2);
 %mylet(myvar2,12);
 %mylet(myvar3,'string');

/* see that they are global inside the macro */
title "Macro scope inside test macro";
proc sql;
    select *
       from dictionary.macros
       where name in('MYVAR','MYVAR2','MYVAR3');
quit;

%mend;
%test;

/* Check to see if they are still global outside the macro */
title "Macro scope outside test macro";
proc sql;
    select *
       from dictionary.macros
       where name in('MYVAR','MYVAR2','MYVAR3');
quit;
```

Comment: Instead of querying the dictionary tables, you can simply do:
%put _global_; or %put _local_; to see the list of global and local macro vars (and their values). You can also do %put _user_; to see only the user defined macro vars (and the values).

Comment: Very true indeed. I chose to use the dictionary table in this case as I've found people are less familiar with these tables and I hoped it might give others new some things to explore. Also it let me easily isolate the three variables in the output no matter what other variables were defined.

Answer (score 4):

If you create the macro variable within open code the macro variable will automatically be added to the global macro symbol table:

```
%let x=1;  
%let y=1;  
%let z=1;
```

This would be **before** you create the larger macro:

```
%macro x;
  <code here>
%mend x;
```

Another alternative would be to create the variables using a data step:

```
data _null_;
    set LIB.DSET;
    x = 1;
    call symput('x',x);
run;
```

Comment: Using `call symputx()` with the `'g'` parameter would be a better approach.

Answer (score 3):

If you create macro variables within a data-step, and that data-step is inside a macro, the macro variables created will be, by default, local in scope to that macro.

Use

```
call symputx('macvar',macval,'g');
```

to create global macro variables.